# I write myself a little bubble sorting code while self-learning python, but couldnt figure out why it doesnt work

Tags: python, sorting

I have been taught to improve the code is the following manner, but the bubble_sort_1 function is still not returning a sorted list, I cannot see which part of my code am I assigning the variables wrongly, because it is now simply returning the same original list

The indentation seems to be messed up while I copy it over, I hope you can understand what I am writing here

students= [

```
('tiffany','A',15),
('jane','B',10),
('ben','C',8),
('simon','A',15),
('john','A',21),
('jimmy','F',1),
('charles','C',9),
('freddy','D',4),
('dave','B',12)]
```

def bubble_sort_1(list):

```
def swap(item1,item2):
    temp=item1
    list[list.index(item1)]=item2
    list[list.index(item2)]=temp

for i in range(len(list)-1):
    if list[i][2]>list[i+1][2]:
    swap(list[i],list[i+1])
```

def bubble_sort_2(list):

```
def swap(index1,index2):
    temp=list[index1]
    list[index1]=list[index2]
    list[index2]=temp

for i in range(len(list)-1):
    if list[i][2]>list[i+1][2]:
    swap(i,(i+1))
```

def bubble_sort_2_improved(list):

```
def swap(index1,index2):
    temp=list[index1]
    list[index1]=list[index2]
    list[index2]=temp
still_need_sorting=True
while still_need_sorting==True:
    still_need_sorting=False
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        if list[i][2]>list[i+1][2]:
        swap(i,(i+1))
        still_need_sorting=True
```

bubble_sort_2_improved(students)

for i in students:
    print(i)

Comment: You have taken a very *interesting* approach to bubble sort. They usually don't recurse and instead feature a `while` loop.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel I am not sure if this is the proper approach, any particular reason why this may not work or less efficient?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because your swap function has a bug, so it never thinks that it has finished. But because of pythons low default recursion depth, and the fact that the number of calls scales linearly with the length of the list that is to be sorted, this implementation will often run into that exception.

Comment: *what can i do or what do i have to learn to improve this?* This is an important question. You should definitely learn to use a debugger: Stepping through your code and seeing what it actually does helps a lot :)

Comment: @ArneRecknagel does that mean I cannot make changes to an iterable while it is been iterated?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel because if such it will enter a endless loop of changes and iteration?

Comment: @user9176512 usually - yes. In this case, that is not the problem though. As long as you don't delete, mutating a list you iterate over can be ok. I just noticed I never told you the bug. In the swap, the second copy operation puts an overwritten object into the second one - and nothing happens.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel oh that means i actually swap it twice! But I have seen such swap function works in some example in the past, i feel like I doing the same thing. In this case, ever time SWAP is executed, nothing happens and thus the loop doesn’t end which cause the depth to be exceeded, is that right?

Comment: @kazemakase alright thank you! I’ll look into debugger and find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to rewrite your code in places where a different approach leads to better results, while keeping the overall idea that you had. If anything is beyond recognition, feel free to ask.

The main points are these:

- Bubble sort works best if you work with classic for-loops instead of for-each loops as python favors (classical in the sense of iterating over list indices instead of the actual objects)
- Swap operations need a temporary object to store the object you will overwrite during the first swap
- Use loops instead of recursion whenever possible, in particular for sorting algorithms that don't use a tree
- Use `if..else` instead of `try..except` [whenever possible](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)
- As a side note, try not to re-use existing names like `list` and `sorted`, it can lead to very weird and hard to debug errors.

  ```
  students = [
      ('tiffany', 'A', 15),
      ('jane', 'B', 10),
      ('ben', 'C', 8),
      ('simon', 'A', 15),
      ('john', 'A', 21),
      ('jimmy', 'F', 1),
      ('charles', 'C', 9),
      ('freddy', 'D', 4),
      ('dave', 'B', 12)]

  def bubble_sort(to_sort):

      def swap(index_1, index_2):     # just use indices directly
          temp = to_sort[index_1]     # this step was missing
          to_sort[index_1] = to_sort[index_2]
          to_sort[index_2] = temp

      we_are_done = False     # slightly more obvious than keeping a count
      while not we_are_done:
          we_are_done = True  # this looks weird, but sadly we don't have do..while in python
          for index in range(len(to_sort) - 1):  # this also avoids the checking-if-next-exists
              if to_sort[index][2] > to_sort[index+1][2]:
                  we_are_done = False  
                  swap(index, index+1)

  bubble_sort(students)  # this function sorts in-place, nothing to return
  print (students)
  ```

Prints:

```
[('jimmy', 'F', 1), ('freddy', 'D', 4), ('ben', 'C', 8), ('charles', 'C', 9), ('jane', 'B', 10), ('dave', 'B', 12), ('tiffany', 'A', 15), ('simon', 'A', 15), ('john', 'A', 21)]
```

Comment: Thank you! That’s a lot of learning points to take note, will definitely help me in learning the language. You’re very helpful!

Comment: i have written another code according to something similar to yours and it worked fine. but when i tried editing mine original code. instead using index as parameter in the SWAP function, i continue to use the items as parameter. it shows no error but the printed list is the same original list. what could have happened?

Comment: What probably happened is that you didn't change the list itself, only the variables you used in the swap functions. If you say `ls=[1]; a=ls[0]; a=2` then that won't change anything about the list: `print(ls); "[1]"`. At some point, you need to change the list itself, via `ls[index] = "something else"`

Comment: In that sense, your approach to get the indices with the `ls.index` function wasn't a bad idea, except that it doesn't work if duplicates are present.

Comment: def bubble_sort(list):    
    def swap(item1,item2):
        temp=item1
        list[list.index(item1)]=item2
        list[list.index(item2)]=temp


    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        if list[i][2]>list[i+1][2]:
            swap(list[i],list[i+1])

this is what i have for the swap, using items instead of index, but i am not reassigning variables here am i? what is my mistake?

Comment: That's a funny bug. It actually happens because of the property of index to stop at the first instance of the search argument it finds. The call `list[list.index(item2)]=temp` finds the location of the student that you swapped in the line just before this one - and restores the state before the swap. Your approach works if you swap the other way round, first `item2` and then `item1`, because the second swap will find the correct swap target that way. You can then also drop the `tmp` assignment because passing the arguments directly to the swap function copies them already.

Comment: oh damn... that’s brilliant! I thought so hard and still couldn’t figure out the reason. Is there a way that I am able to find bugs systematically(like a debugger that I’ve heard) in the future or is this practice and experience?

Comment: Everyone adapts their own way to debug. The best way is probably to use the debugger of an IDE. By setting a breakpoint in the code you suspect, you can constantly keep an eye of the state of all variables and will - probably - find the mismatch soon enough. I personally like the PyCharm debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
def bubble_sort(L):
    """(list)->list
sort the items of list and return list
>>> LL=[7,3,5,2]
>>> bubble_sort(LL)
[2, 3, 5, 7]
"""
    #index of last element of the list
    end=len(L)-1
    while end!=0:
        # buuble sort passes to the list and move one large item at end of list
        for i in range(end):

            if L[i]>L[i+1]:
                L[i],L[i+1]=L[i+1],L[i]
        end=end-1
    return L

>>> students= [
    ('tiffany','A',15),
    ('jane','B',10),
    ('ben','C',8),
    ('simon','A',15),
    ('john','A',21),
    ('jimmy','F',1),
    ('charles','C',9),
    ('freddy','D',4),
    ('dave','B',12)]

>>> bubble_sort(students)
```

It give output

> [('ben', 'C', 8), ('charles', 'C', 9), ('dave', 'B', 12), ('freddy',
>   'D', 4), ('jane', 'B', 10), ('jimmy', 'F', 1), ('john', 'A', 21),
>   ('simon', 'A', 15), ('tiffany', 'A', 15)]

Data Structure is list of tuple

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `swap()` function doesn't work correctly. After it does:

```
list[list.index(item1)]=item2
```

then when the next line uses `list.index(item2)` it may find the index that you just put `item2` into, rather than its original index. You should get both indexes before reassigning either of them.

```
def swap(item1, item2):
    index1 = list.index(item1)
    index2 = list.index(item2)
    list[index1] = item2
    list[index2] = item1
```

But all your use of `list.index()` is a very poor way to do this, since it has to search the list repeatedly. It also means the list can't have any duplicates, because `index()` will only find the first match. Instead, you should iterate over the indexes and pass them to the `swap()` function.

```
for i in range(len(list)-1):
    student = list[i]
    next = list[i+1]
    if student[2] > next[2]:
        swap(i, i+1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I know my code is inefficient but couldn’t think of an more elegant way to do this, thank you again.

Comment: I have another question, this means that we will only iterate through the list one time right, but there could be situation that the list is still not sort after one round of iteration

Answer (score 0):

You had 2 issues with your code

1. you needed to keep pos1 and pos2 of the items you wanted to swap, otherwise you ended up putting the same item back where it was...
2. in the recursive call of "bubble_sort()" - you should return what the recursive call returns - add a "return" statement there.

Besides that - because list are mutable you don't need to assign the end result to "sorted" because the original "students" already holds the correct output

This code works:

```
students= [
('tiffany','A',15),
('jane','B',10),
('ben','C',8),
('simon','A',15),
('john','A',21),
('jimmy','F',1),
('charles','C',9),
('freddy','D',4),
('dave','B',12)]


def bubble_sort(list):
    def swap(item1,item2):
        pos1 = list.index(item1)
        pos2 = list.index(item2)
        list[pos1] = item2
        list[pos2]=item1

    count=0

    for student in list:
        try:
            next=list[(list.index(student))+1]

            if student[2]>next[2]:
                swap(student,next)
                count+=1
        except IndexError:
            break


    if count==0 :
        return list
    else:
        return bubble_sort(list)

sorted=bubble_sort(students)

print (sorted)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi! I tried running this code, but it prints back the same original list, I don’t understand why

Comment: I just ran it both in Python 2.7 and 3.6 - same results - [('jimmy', 'F', 1), ('freddy', 'D', 4), ('ben', 'C', 8), ('charles', 'C', 9), ('jane', 'B', 10), ('dave', 'B', 12), ('tiffany', 'A', 15), ('simon', 'A', 15), ('john', 'A', 21)]

Comment: Make sure you have the correct indents - the code here was kinda messed by the indention - edited